# Visual basic copy specific part from textbox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, url, textbox, visual-studio-2012, copy

Hello how do i copy a specific part from a textbox to an other textbox in visual basic

Example :
I load a text file to the textbox then the textbox contains this :

Newest version : 1.0.1.1
Download link : http://www.downloadlinkhere.nl/

i want to copy the url to an other text box how do i do that???
I am using : Visual studio 2012
and programming language : Visual Basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, assuming (as in your example) that there isn't any text to discard after the URL and that "http" will only occur once in the text:

```
TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(TextBox1.Text.IndexOf("http"))
```

If your situation is in fact more complex than your example you might want to look at [Regular Expressions](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/RegexNET).